# How to make queue calling in salesforce using Twilio?

Tags: apex, integration, twilio

I am integrating my salesforce with Twilio to make calls.I am able to call person individually. But my requirement is to allow multiple persons to be called one by one using a queuing in Twilio. How is it achievable in apex?

Comment: Have you checked this link http://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/queues.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag in  tag to make calls to multiple numbers.
Please follow this this link.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue